# iOS, create object for array

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I have JSON data coming in using AFNetworking.
The `responseObject` holds an array of objects like so: `[{"id":"XX", "description":"XX"}, {"id":"XX", "description":"XX"}]`. This content is copied across to an `NSArray`, where by value access is obtained with `objectAtIndex: valueForKey:`.

I know object-c is overly complicated so I'm guessing that this is wishful thinking, but how would I go about creating a quick object to use in the event that `responseObject` is nil?

(any committed object-c coders, you'll have to excuse my bluntness. working with higher level languages causes logical ignorance)

```
if responseObject is nil
  destinationArray= [{id:XX, description:XX}, {id:XX, description:XX}]
else
  destinationArray = responseObject
```

Comment: You're right -- Objective-C is overly complicated,except when compared to all the languages that claim to be simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with Objective-C literals:

```
if (!responseObject) {
  destinationArray= @[
      @{ @"id":@"XX",
         @"description":@"XX"},
      @{ @"id":@"XX",
         @"description":@"XX"}
  ];
} else {
  destinationArray = responseObject;
}
```

Where:

- `NSArray` objects are `@[` ... `]`.
- `NSDictionary` objects are `@{` ... `}`.
- `NSString` objects are `@"string"`.
- `NSNumber` objects are  `@(1)`, `@(1.2f)`, `@(1.2)`, `@(YES)`.

Comment: i ended up solving the null issue at the API end, however in event of unexpected null i will use this. thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0):

The data you are showing has 2 parts:

Multiple NSDictionaries, there are many ways to create them:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:...,nil];
```

Or you can define them by using its literal

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"id":@"XX", @"description":@"XX"};
```

An NSArray, to create an array you can use several options:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:...,nil];
```

Or, like before you can use the literal definition:

```
NSArray *array = @[dictionary1,dictionary2];
```

So, you can create the entire object like this:

```
if (responseObject == nil) {
    destinationArray = @[@{@"id":@"XX", @"description":@"XX"}, 
                         @{@"id":@"XX", @"description":@"XX"}];
} else {
    destinationArray = responseObject;
}
```

Read more at: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/FoundationTypesandCollections/FoundationTypesandCollections.html